# Mono Compile Stuck on mscorlib

Tags: mono, cross-compiling

I am completely stumped. I am trying to compile Mono using a eglibc toolchain generated using Buildroot and Crosstool-NG. I **cannot** build any versions after 3.0.3. Version 3.0.3 builds and executes great...later versions hang while trying to compile mscorlib. The output where it hangs is listed below.

Using strace it seems like the compilation of mscorlib completed successfully, but that all of the remaining jobs are waiting for something to finish that never does (my cpu% drops to 0 so nothing is happening).

Any suggestions to try are greatly appreciated. Here is the make output when it hangs:

--- *PRIOR OUTPUT OMITTED*

Making all in runtime

make[2]: Entering directory `/home/test/dev/mono-3.0.7/runtime'

if test -w /home/test/dev/mono-3.0.7/mcs; then :; else chmod -R +w /home/test/dev/mono-3.0.7/mcs; fi

cd /home/test/dev/mono-3.0.7/mcs && make --no-print-directory -s NO_DIR_CHECK=1 PROFILES=' net_2_0 net_3_5    ' CC='i686-buildroot-linux-gnu-gcc' all-profiles

Bootstrap compiler: Mono C# compiler version 2.10.8.1

MCS     [build] mscorlib.dll **<---- Hangs at this output forever**

Thank You!

Comment: try doing `make V=1` to see more output; also, what distro are you using?

Comment: I am building on Debian 7. I was using Debian 6 and decided to create a Debian 7 VM to see if maybe new tools solved the problem. Thank you for the suggestion I will give that a try and post back. Today I tried switching for eglibc in crosstool-ng to glibc (gcc 4.5.3 & glibc 2.11) and I get a segmentation fault when it tries to build the exact thing.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion of make V=1. It appears that the following is causing the hang: MONO_PATH="./../../class/lib/basic:$MONO_PATH" /home/test/dev/mono-3.0.7/runtime/mono-wrapper  ./../../class/lib/basic/basic.exe [REMOVED ]. In the 3.0.3 and earlier tags this runs and exits. Later revs just hang...even with no argurments I get "error CS2008: NO files..." and it never returns to the prompt. Any thoughts?

Comment: Here is the stack trace (last 4 lines) from gdb:
#0  0xb7702424 in __kernel_vsyscall ()
#1  0xb75c6dc4 in pthread_join ()
   from /home/test/dev/test2/host/usr/i686-buildroot-linux-gnu/lib/libpthread.so.0
#2  0x08250806 in GC_pthread_join (thread=3009162048, retval=retval@entry=0x0)
    at pthread_support.c:1343
#3  0x081e27b1 in mono_gc_cleanup () at gc.c:1218
#4  0x081d9f37 in mono_runtime_cleanup (domain=domain@entry=0x34e58)
    at appdomain.c:355

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks to knocte's comment I managed to stumble my way into the answer. I don't know why, but changing my eglibc library to 2_13 allows my Mono compilation to complete successfully. I was originally using 2_15. I also tried 2_14 to be thorough and it also fails by hanging at the same point. The step mentioned in the step above seems to deadlock.

So to summarize, Mono versions 3.0.3 and earlier compiled fine with an eglibc 2_15 buildroot toolchain. Mono versions 3.0.4 and later do not, but build successfully with an eglibc 2_13 buildroot toolchain.

I don't know if the issue is in Mono, eglibc, or both. I hope this helps somebody somewhere sometime given how much time I wasted on it!

Answer (score 0):

For me the issue was caused by the antivirus software (Avast). Even if I added the mono folder to the "Scan Exclusions" list and disabled the protection shield, it still continued scanning `mono/mini/.libs/mono-sgen.exe`. After uninstalling the antivirus, the build did not hang and finished successfully.

I'm not suggesting you should uninstall your antivirus. I just mentioned what worked for me. FYI, I reinstalled the antivirus after the build finished.